# What are some unique game identifiers that I may have in in my PS3?

Tags: ps3

My house was broken into 2 weeks ago and 27 of my PS3 games were stolen, my PS3 fat was left untouched however.

I've noticed a kijiji ad that has come up and there is a match with 26 of my games. Not only that but the seller noted which ones were new and used and that matches up with my games as well. (Because sometimes you buy a game and just can't find time to play it)

Suffice to say I think these have a high probability of being my games.

I am thinking that perhaps the thief hasn't bothered to check all the games and I know that when I enter an unlock code for a game I put the paper back in the case.

So for dragon age I had an unlock code for the golem and for Dead Space 2 I had the online unlock code. Is there any way of checking what my codes were that I entered in for my PS3 account?

Comment: If you're thinking that these identifiers may be of use to you in claiming the item as the one that was stolen from you, good luck. A few years back, I couldn't get back a GBA **that had my freaking name engraved on it**. But hey, maybe the cops around your place will be cooperative, who knows.

Comment: @Nigralbus I currently work for the police so I really hope so.

Comment: Heh. Guess that could help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My house was broken into once, and the detectives in charge of my case seemed only concerned about hard evidence or any unique marking that could not be easily removed from the items that were stolen. Specifically, they asked if I had engraved any of the items, had the original serial numbers, receipts, or if I had altered the packaging or item in any specific way. Telling officers about any specific codes you had in the packaging may help them identify the items as being yours, and once the items are processed through evidence, will allow you to claim them. It will probably be deemed too circumstantial to serve as evidence in court, however.

One thing that may help you, is to note that each game is generally wrapped in a thick plastic coating that will attract finger prints. If they locate the games and then find that your finger prints are all over them, then you are in business. The same could be said about the discs themselves, which have even more conspicuous prints.

I would notify the officer handling your case ASAP about the ad, and anything that you believe is a POTENTIAL unique identifier in any of those game cases. I would also make them alert to the fact that these items probably have your fingerprints in an easily visible spot.

The point is, you have no reason NOT to alert the police to this information, and you should do so to help out as much as you can. What they do with the information is their call, but at least you will have done your part.

Comment: Thanks Tater, I already have forwarded on the relevant information to the officer who was investigating. Unlock codes seem pretty unique to me so I'm hoping that this would help in identifying that a game would be mine. Or if there is some other method that Sony or a game company takes to have a uniqueness with a game or disk.

Comment: I think it will certainly help, provided you or the police can obtain some sort of record from Sony to tie the code to your playstation if it is indeed still in the case. Have you purchased any "season pass" DLC on any of the games? That might REALLY help.

Comment: @Biff MaGriff Something is either unique or not. It cannot be pretty unique or have uniqueness.